# EWS exchange rooms view

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I need to make an application which shows the current exchange meeting rooms and for each room whether the hour is free or busy. The user can give a daterange of max 5 days to see the result.

I have made a construction but it 2 slow to use as it takes up to 3 seconds to get all the information from only 3 meeting rooms (while in the future it will be more around 20).

This is how I work:

1. Authenticate through AutodiscoverUrl function: **service.AutodiscoverUrl(email, password)**.
2. After been given a startdate and enddate with 5 days in it, I first get all the available meetingrooms with **service.GetRooms("room@roomlist.com")**
3. I iterate through the found meetingrooms and use the function **service.GetUserAvailability(room,...)** to get the calenderevents.
4. Then I have a class which tells me the hours of the day and I check the found calenderevents of the room to see whether an hour is busy or not.

Now I have my collection of rooms with calenderevents and  the indication whether an hour is busy or not.

But is there another, faster way? As said this takes up to 2/3 seconds for only 3 rooms in a daterange of 5 days.

Comment: Have you timed the different parts of your process to identify which step is taking the most time. You can then post the code to that section to see if anyone can identify a better solution.

Comment: Like Scrobi said, you should time your code using something like the [Stopwatch Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the GetUserAvailability request for each room, as you iterate through, or batching the users together?  The availability call can return info on multiple users (100 is the hard limit I recall).  It's likely one big call will be more efficient than multiple single calls.